# gmail_smtp.git messed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gmail, bcrypt

I am trying to get gmail working on Heroku and followed the "tutorial" on http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/11/9/tech_sending_email_with_gmail/

When I did the `install git://github.com/adamwiggins/gmail_smtp.git` things got messed up.

The install didn't work and I got the error message:

`` Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) with native extensions /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:551:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError) ``

```
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
Makefile:148: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
```

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/user/Dropbox/work/project/git:/github.com/adamwiggins/gmail_smtp.git/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/user/Dropbox/work/project/git:/github.com/adamwiggins/gmail_smtp.git/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out

So now I can't do anything.

What I would like to do is uninstall the whole thing, but I don't know how to do it and I haven't been able to install bcrypt-ruby in any way I can think of (not that I am experienced enough to think of that many).

I tried rm -rf on git: hoping that that is where the info on the install is, but that didn't help either.

Could someone enlighten me on where the info after the 'install git://' is stored or how to remove/uninstall it or any other way for me to have some progress. I am officially stuck..

Cheers Carl

Comment: Never mind this post. I didn't manage to install correctly. I got it to work at Heroku, but not in dev. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855870/gmail-on-heroku-with-rails-3 if you have a clue to what I might be doing wrong.